# why the element of unit vector must lie in $[-1,1]$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given any vector $\pmb a$, let

$$\pmb{\hat a} = \frac{\pmb{a}}{\sqrt{\pmb{a}' \pmb{a}}}$$

Of course, I know $\pmb{\hat a}$ has unit length. Then the magnitudes of $\hat{a}_1, \hat{a}_2,\ldots , \hat{a}_p$ (p dimension) all lie in the interval $[-1,1]$. I don't know why. I only know the whole vector has length 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is simply because
$$
|a_i|\leq \|a\|,\quad 1\le i\le n
$$
for any vector $a=(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$. Here $\|a\|$ denotes the length of the vector $a$.